# nbsp in displayeditor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to separate figures.

```
@model string
@{
    @String.Format("{0:### ### ###}", Int32.Parse(Model))
}
```

How change spaces to nbsp? Encoding hindrance me. Ampersand changes to `& a m p ;`

Comment: if `&nbsp;` gets encoded to `&amp;nbsp;`, then you've got double-encoding...

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent Razor from automatically encoding the string by using the Html.Raw function:

```
@model string
@{
    @Html.Raw(string.Format("{0:###&nbsp;###&nbsp;###}", Int32.Parse(Model)))
}
```

Obviously you should exercise caution when using this function, but if you're just outputting an integer you should be OK.